# Upper bound on trace distance of subsystems based on full system

Tags: quantum-state, trace-distance, trace-norm

If we have the following upper bound on the sum of trace distances:

$$
\frac{1}{N} \sum_{a, b}||p_1(a | b) \rho_{ab} - p_2(a | b) \sigma_{ab}|| \le \epsilon,
$$
where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are two probability distributions and $\rho_{ab}$ and $\sigma_{ab}$ are quantum states depending on $a, b$.
Then, what is the best that we could say about the following in terms of $\epsilon$:

$$
||\rho_{ab} - \sigma_{ab}|| \le ? 
$$

Answer (score 2):

In general I would imagine not much. For simplicity consider the case where $p_1 = p_2$. Then the worst case would be that for all $(i,j) \neq (a,b)$ we have $\rho_{ij} = \sigma_{ij}$. Thus the entire difference in the first equation is coming only from the difference between the pair $\rho_{ab}$ and $\sigma_{ab}$. In such a case you'd have
$$
\|\rho_{ab} - \sigma_{ab}\| \leq \frac{N \epsilon}{p(a|b)}.
$$
which could even be bigger than the trivial bound of $1$ unless $\epsilon < 1/N$.

Without more context to the problem I don't see how you'd get around this.

Comment: I see your point, Rammus. Thanks a lot for the clarification.